# Is it possible to add an or condition to an if statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

So recently I've switched over from python to java and was trying to recreate some of the projects that I made on python in java. The first thing that came to mind was a quiz.

Basically, to create a quiz, I define an answer variable to the answer then use the scanner method in java to detect the user's input. After that, I use an if statement to see if the input equals the answer.

ex.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "dog";
        System.out.println("What is a common furry animal");
        String input = scan.nextLine( );
        if (input.equals(answer))
        {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Inncorect");
        }

    }
}
```

Now that all works but the user doesn't know the exact casing of the answer variable which means if the variable was "dog" and he input "Dog" it would be incorrect. So if it was possible to create an "or" condition to an if statement it would be awesome if someone let me know.

-Thanks

Comment: Simple solution might be `if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) { ... }`, but, to answer your question, you could use `if (input.equals(answer) || input.toLowerCase().equals(answer.toLowerCase())) { ... }` where `||` is "or" and `&&` is "and" ;)

Comment: Unlike Python, which uses keywords for logical operators, Java (and C, C++, C#, Objective C, JavaScript, etc.) use punctuation tokens for these operators. Thus `and` is `&&`, `or` is `||`, and `not` is `!`.

Comment: When diving into a new language, it's always good to start with the documentation.

In this case, you want to look at the operators section: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

You may also want to consult the object reference for the Java object String, which is not a primitive like it is in some languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `or` any condition in Java, use the conventional `||` to separate conditions. In your case it would be something like:

```
if (input.equals(answer) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
```

Although you probably just need the Java method `equalsIgnoreCase` as the lone condition in the first place.

Comment: "probably just need" ? Why even go down the road of suggesting redundant code?

Comment: @John3136 I was answering how to do exactly what OP was asking for, then gave him a suggestion to make it better.